Google Service Account Credential File Not found error while deploying my project into Render
i have problem in deploying the spring boot project in to my render account and got credential not found exception. i used Vertex AI and it takes google service account authentication with credential json file. but i don't know how to provide that json file into render. as in local development server i used gcloud cli using th ebelow link https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#gcloud-cli.
I tried to deploy my spring boot application to my render account. i have created a Gpt clone using Google Vertex Ai. here to use google vertex ai we have to provide a google service account credential. now when i used to run the application into development server(in my localhost) i used the Google cloud command line and generate the json file in my local computer. i used https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#gcloud-cli this website for the refrence. now i dont know who to set that json file to my render environment. i tried to give the create a render environment  variable with name GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and value as my json text. also tried to give json file google storage(public link) as the value but it still give Io exception like this
java.io.IOException: Error reading credential file from environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, value 'file path from google storage public path': File does not exist.
help me to get rid out of this.
need any more information ?? just reply me i am ready to give any information wants but i really need solution

You appear to have set your GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to be a URL - it's meant to the name of a local file. I don't know anything about render and whether you can deploy a file alongside your code, but that's basically what you need to do in order to use GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.
